# docker run local script without host volumes

Tags: database, shell, docker, docker-compose

The goal is to add data to my database server containers of a multi-container web app from a download using curl once the database containers are running. I can do this from docker-compose.yml or from docker run independent of the web app, as long as I use host volumes.

*How do I do it without using host volumes or web app specific Dockerfiles?*

Docker Compose example with host volumes:

```
dbinit:
build: ./webtools_config/initdb
command: bash -c "/tmp/webtools_config/dbinit.sh"
volumes:
 - ./webtools_config:/tmp/webtools_config
links:
 - db1
 - db2
```

Example of a docker run, that I would like to pass a *script file local to the docker client* such as ./dbinit.sh:

```
docker run -a stdin -a stdout -i -t \
--link dir_db1_1:db1 \
--link dir_db2_1:db2 \
initdb /bin/sh -c "./dbinit.sh"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solutions I have found are:

```
docker run tomdavidson/initdb bash -c "`cat initdb.sh`"
```

and

Set an ENV VAR equal to your script and set up your Docker image to run the script (of course one can ADD/COPY and use host volumes but that is not this question), for example:

```
docker run -d -e ADD_INIT_SCRIPT="`cat custom-script.sh`" tomdavidson/debian
```

tomdavidson/debian's CMD runs a script with:

```
if [ "${ADD_INIT_SCRIPT}" != "**None**" ]; then
  echo "Executing ADD_INIT_SCRIPT ..."
  bash -c "${ADD_INIT_SCRIPT}"
fi
```

https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/tomdavidson/debian/

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you can *eliminate* linking host volumes by **building** image with this script.

Your Dockerfile:

```
# Dockerfile 
...
ADD your-script-on-host.sh /app/your-script-in-container.sh
RUN /app/your-script-in-container.sh
# Your CMD here
```

Note that way you will be able to update and run this script only while **building** the image.

Comment: thank you neciu, but I dont see anything problematic with linking. Would best practice be to have the initdb image be unique to the web app rather than a generic way to run the script?